# Fortune 500 Software Engineer Absolutely Bored, want to become independent

Tags: startup

I'm 47 years old Software Engineer/Architect, I work for very prestigious Fortune 500 company and have a 6 figure salary.. and I'm bored like the HELL... I'm sick of the politics, the bureaucracy.. and Idiot Project Managers that get their job only because the know very well how to manipulate people with elaborated and sophisticated verbal BS...

Yeap.. I discovered kind of late that Corporate World is not for me.. so I want to start my own company and I have a serious 20+ year experience background.. I have been all my life very passionate about technology.. and for years I was a terrific Software Developer.. I still preserve my skills and my passion for coding.. have a plethora of ideas for new Applications..(and I'm talking about complete Systems.. not simple pretty programs like the majority of newbies will come up with)  BUT... I'm 3 years shy from being 50 years old and...no savings enough to survive for more than 2 months.

I've been contemplating different formulas to start my dream of having my own Software Company.. but all of them are reduce to getting the answer to this questions...

- How much money can I make as an Independent Software Engineer..?

I know that there are Thousand of guys out there with different background and years of experience working independently.. I know that the competition is outrageously wild... but I want to have more specific numbers and statistics.. and a good idea of what is the most lucrative software area today and in the years to come.... I will enormously appreciate all your good comments and information.. If I end up starting my company an turn into a millionaire I sure will remember you and reward you with cash... :)

Comment: Questions about startups have nothing to do with questions about code

Comment: Will be closed, but try working as an early employee at a startup.  Also, what kind of lifestyle are you living to make 6-figures and have no savings, or are you excluding equity?!

Comment: You can go here (another SE website) for questions about startups : http://answers.onstartups.com/

Comment: @Marc.. thanks I just posted my question there...